# Flash Page Flip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

What properties are used to animate a Flash "book"? Are there any open source projects that I can use to make something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.megazine3.de/

I would take a look there.  Pretty easy API and covers pretty much everything you would need in a Flash "book."